# Cloud storage pricing confusion

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, cloud, google-cloud-storage, price

I have a basic question relating to Cloud storage pricing. I see many clould service providers mentioning charges, for example "$1 per 25 GB per month". Let us consider two cases -

1. If I am storing 25 GB every day but deleting data of previous day then I will eventually have 25 GB storage on last day of the month. In this case my charges can be $1.
2. If I am storing 25 GB every day and deleting data of previous day, but I wrote 25 * 30 GB amount of data entire month. So even if I was cleaning the data my total storage amounts to 750 GB and so my charges should be 750/25 * 1 = $30.

What will be my cost at the end of the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage charges only apply for the duration of time that data existed, which is your 1st case.

Put differently, storing one 50 GB object for 10 days costs the same as storing two 25 GB objects for 5 days each (or one 500 GB object for 1 day, for that matter).

See also the second point [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-notes) about prorated storage charges.

In your 2nd case, "wrote 25 * 30 GB" actually describes network ingress -- which is free (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing) under "General network usage")

Comment: @Iot Thanks for the reply. One more thing, is cost generally calculated per hour basis or per minute/second basis (even if price is mentioned per hour). For example, if I store my data for 1 hour 20 minues, then is it going to be rounded off as 2 hours or it will be billed for 100 minues only?

Comment: See docs link. "Storage charges are prorated to the sub-second for each object"

Comment: @Iot Yes, it is there in the doc. Didn't read the doc completely. Sorry for being lazy (or may be busy). Thanks for your kind help. Cheers!